# Raspberry PI problem switching 230VAC fan

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi

I'm using a ULN2003 to switch an opto-isolated 8 channel 5V relay. The 230V lights works perfectly but when I try to switch a ceiling fan (sometimes) the relay module trips, switching on all the relays (the fan is connected to a speed regulator).

I need your guidance.

This is the schematic:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the relay module trips switching on all the relays".

Comment: Anyhow, the fan is an inductive load, you need to derate the relay's max current by a factor of 5 to 10 to account for that.

Comment: It sounds like an EMI problem, especially if it happens on turning off the fan. EMI can be conducted or radiated. First thing you should check whether really the relay board malfunctions, or whether the Raspberry Pi turns on all the output. If the relay board has no R/C-type "snubber", you might need to add some measure against conducted EMI..

Comment: can you please give link for buying a R/C snubber. Thanks

Comment: Not to mention that this looks like one of those cheapy weepy eBay/Ali/Whatever Relay boards, which should seriously not be used with anything close to mains AC, as they are horrendously badly designed when it comes to creep and clearance.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Karcher wrote, looks like EMI problem.
First try to remove speed regulator from circuit, problem might disappears. If so, turn it back and try to understand who "turn lights on": ULN2003 or Raspberry.
I bet it's ULN2003 - you need to add extra Ceramic Capacity 47nF to power pins of your ULN2003.

Comment: The ULN2003 doesn't have a power pin.  It is just a bunch of darlington transistors with all their emitters connected together, and to the Ground pin.

Comment: will a R/C snubber solve the problem http://in.element14.com/roxburgh/xe1201/rc-network-250v-0-1uf-120ohm-pcb/dp/1187649